# Has Max-Q historically been a common failure point in rocket launches?

Tags: launch, failure, max-q

I believe that it's common knowledge that Max-Q is the point in which a rocket is undergoing the maximum dynamic stress during a launch and ascent.  But, how often have rockets actually been destroyed or failed at this point (or close to it) during launch **due to Max-Q stresses**?  I've seen videos of many launches which fail with rapid disassembly before this point, but can't really recall that Max-Q is a statistically large factor in rocket launch failures.  Am I mistaken, or have rocket designs evolved such that Max-Q is a known factor that's been successfully planned into rocket design and manufacture?

Comment: The trajectories/throttle settings are designed to not exceed the Q limit.  In other words this is a known constraint that is managed.  When they blow up, it's usually due to an unmanaged factor.

Comment: The significance of Max Q is not so much that everyone can breathe a sigh of relief when it's over, rather that it's an important event that the trajectory and sequencing are designed around.

Comment: MaxQ could mean doom in case the engines fail to throttle down when required. It's an unlikely scenario and I doubt it ever occurred but I don't think it's impossible.

Comment: I believe the Maiden flight of the Ariane V was destroyed because of excess aerodynamic stresses

Comment: The [Ariane V failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(spacecraft)#Launch_failure) was caused by a software error.

Answer (score 11):

Both of the shuttle flights that suffered fatal accidents encountered significant wind shear events that took place very close to max q. I'm not aware that this was directly linked to the accidents but there were people involved in the STS-107 accident investigation who were very suspicious that this was a coincidence.

[STS-51L:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-51-L_Mission_timeline)

Max q was at 59 seconds.  Max vehicle response to wind shear was at 61.724 seconds.

51-L Accident Report remarks on the max-Q / wind shear / booster leak correlation:

> Additional structural loads resulted from turbulence. Flight 51-L
> experienced the most severe turbulence of any Shuttle flight and,
> although the loads were within the allowable design limits, those
> design limits did not consider a joint that had already failed. It is
> unknown how much the combined effect of wind gust loads, maneuvering loads and an increase in thrust contributed to the accident. But the combined effects of these forces could have dislodged
> the burned material at the previously breached section of the joint.
>
> 10. Shortly after the vehicle was loaded by these turbulent
>     forces, at T+58 seconds, a flame appeared from the same general
>     region where the puffs of smoke had been seen. But, this time the
>     joint was continuously breached by the burning propellant gases.
>     In a little over two seconds, the flame had grown and acted as a
>     blowtorch to burn through the hydrogen tank. The appearance of
>     the flame at this time is also indicative of a damaged primary 0-
>     ring and failure of the secondary O-ring to seal...

From *INVESTIGATION OF THE CHALLENGER
ACCIDENT
REPORT
OF THE
COMMITTEE ON
SCIENCE AND TECHNOLOGY
HOUSE OF REPRESENTATIVES
NINETY-NINTH CONGRESS
SECOND SESSION*

[STS-107:](https://spaceflightnow.com/shuttle/sts107/030311caib/)

Max q was at ~58 seconds (I'm reading off a [graph](https://history.nasa.gov/columbia/Troxell/Columbia%20Web%20Site/CAIB/CAIB%20Website/news/STS%20107%20Working%20Scenario/sts107workingscenario_1.pdf)). The wind shear started at 57 seconds. The foam debris release was at ~82 seconds.

> STS-107 experienced a wind shear during the period of maximum dynamic pressure
> starting at 57 seconds MET (Mach 1.27). The wind shear was due to a rapid change in
> the out-of-plane wind velocity of -37.7 feet per second over a 1200 foot altitude range
> starting at approximately 32,000 ft (as shown in Figure 3-21). Immediately after the
> vehicle flew through this altitude range, its side-slip angle began to increase in the
> negative direction, reaching a value of approximately –1.75 degrees at 60 seconds.
> This value of side-slip angle is a new flight experience value for MET 60 seconds (as
> shown in Figure 3-22). Post-flight data review indicates that the new flight experience
> side slip event not the result of the wind shear itself. Instead, it was the direct result of
> a difference in the L - 4:35 minutes balloon measurement, upon which orbiter guidance
> commands were updated on launch day, and the actual winds flown through by the
> orbiter during launch and ascent. Figure 3-21 highlights the difference in these two
> winds in this altitude region (a 25 foot per second increase in out-of-plane magnitude
> pre-launch compared to a 12 foot per second reduction in magnitude as experienced by
> the vehicle)

Quote from the "Working Scenario" linked above.

I just read of another incident, a Proton launch in Feb 1969, where the "newly designed" payload fairing collapsed at max q.  (Soviet Robots in the Solar System, Huntress & Marov, p. 195).

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation. Let's please not feed conspiracies. Just because two events were observed together twice, doesn't mean one is the cause of the other. Let's leave the analysis to the investigators who had access to all the facts. This is how, in the age of information, we wind knowing less than before.

Comment: @Alex I'm open to corrections if any of the facts I stated are incorrect.

Comment: it's not the facts, but the way you use them. We know that two rockets failed near max Q. We do not know that max Q caused the failures. Let's be reasonable and accept the limits of what we know, please. I've frankly had it with the wild speculations and conspiracies that people so carelessly seem to embrace nowadays. We all have brains to think.

Comment: You should read the CAIB and the 51-L official accident reports. These correlations are in there.

Comment: No one is denying the correlations. We do know two rockets failed near max Q. But did max Q cause the failures? If every day a red cardinal sings when the sun comes up, did the cardinal cause the sun to rise? Can we even say that the sun woke up the cardinal, who, like us, has an internal clock of its own, which would cause it to rise even on the darkest day? Point is, correlation does not imply causation. We know the correlation---that two rockets failed near max Q. That correlation, *by itself*, is not enough to suppose a causal link---that max Q led to the failures.

Comment: Did you even look at what the question here is? *Has Max-Q historically been a common failure point in rocket launches?*  You will find no red cardinals in those accident reports - only things that had, or were suspected to have, bearings on the failures.

Comment: We perfectly well know Challenger was doomed the instant the SRBs were lit, Max-Q had absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: @LorenPechtel It's cool that you know that, the investigating commission wasn't so sure. "It is unknown how much the combined effect of wind gust loads, maneuvering loads and an increase in thrust contributed to the accident. "

Comment: Wow. OK. So you pointed out that two rockets failed near max Q. You pointed out a correlation, and a weak one at that, given that your sample includes only two data points. And not only is your correlation questionable, it does not establish causation. The fact that the rockets were near max Q may well have been coincidence. It would take more investigation to convincingly show whether max Q could have caused the failures. Sheer speculation is not investigation. And so all you accomplished was feed a suspicion---that *maybe* max Q has caused rocket failures. How does that answer the question?

Comment: I mean, I get it. People like to speculate. What if. It's fun. It's even gratifying if you manage to convince others that you know something they don't. But at the end of the day, empty speculation is just that. And what we need is solid facts, something that gets us just a little bit closer to what truly happened. And the only way to be sure of that is to be rigorous in our thinking. And if you can't tell correlation from causation apart, then we're in deep trouble. Because that's where baseless and deeply counterproductive conspiracy theories come from. It helps if people just *think*.

Comment: BTW, that remark from the investigating commission merely suggests that other factors could have *aggravated* the failure---not caused it. Huge difference between aggravating a failure and causing it. If you burn a chair to the ground, the fire destroyed it. If you kick the chair as it burns, the kick may aggravate the damage, but it's still the fire that doomed it.

Comment: Exactly what *conspiracy* are you accusing me of promoting?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Sure, the winds probably played a role as to when it blew up.  That doesn't change the fact that the booster was burning against the fuel tank.

Comment: @LorenPechtel if you read the Rogers Commision report one of their conclusions was that a valid reading  of the data is that the breach had 'scabbed over' with slag until the dynamics of responding to the wind shear broke it open again, and then the flame burned through the LH2 tank.

Comment: "Alternatively, the O-ring gap could 
have been resealed by deposition of a 
fragile buildup of aluminum oxide and 
other combustion debris. This resealed 
section of the joint could have been 
disturbed by thrust vectoring, Space 
Shuttle motion and flight loads induced by changing winds aloft. " Rogers Commission Vol 1 p 72

Answer (score 9):

Rockets usually fail early in flight, within a minute of liftoff, or in the vacuum stage since that is hard to simulate on Earth. You can see a list of rocket failures [here](http://www.astronautix.com/t/thewrongstuhiclefailures.html). The structure is one of the most reliable rocket parts, the failures are mainly related to fuel pumping and bad design decisions.

Comment: Nice answer! I can understand why the question is interesting; in every live broadcast I've watched there is almost always some significant commenting made during the Max-Q phase. I wonder if it is such a "big deal" because there's nothing else to talk about then, or because it's costly (in terms of propellant/payload masses) to slow down or hold back thrust during this phase, rather than because it's a particularly dangerous phase, which it seems it isn't?

Comment: This does not answer the question about failures *due to Max-Q stresses*

Comment: @uhoh Max-Q is known well in advance. It *is* a dangerous phase if you simply plow into it unprepared. But since its known so well beforehand, the rocket throttles down and stays within structural limits. Afterwards, you can throttle up again. It *is* a significant event in the flight, but not really something to worry about. NASA did multiple tests to ensure that the LES for mercuy/gemini/apollo would work at max-q since that is the point where the LES gets most stresses and an abort is most dangerous. But again, the LES can handle it, its designed for it. I think its more historical relevanc

Comment: @Polygnome yes I understand that. Take a look again at my comment. I'm discussing why one might ask [the question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21171/12102) in the first place, and suggesting that it might be related to the fact that broadcasts bring it up in every launch as if it were a particularly notable event, and then suggesting that while it is not particularly notable in terms of safety, it might be worth exploring why it is always brought to the attention to the viewing public in such a visible way each time. If you can address that instead in some way, that would be great!

Comment: @uhoh I think its brought up because its the most notable event during that flight phase, and because it is somewhat significant for manned launches, because any LES would have the hardest time during that phase. The question is, why *wouldn't* you bring it up? Sport commentators bring up lots of tangential information all the time. Its only natural a commentator for a launch would do the same. In fact, they bring up lots of other tangential stuff as well.

Comment: @Polygnome ok you've got me thinking! So I've asked the follow-up question [What are the aerodynamic, structural, control, and other challenges around max-Q for an unmanned rocket?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22183/12102).

Comment: @uhoh I think reporters like to mention it because they have a propensity to sensationalize things, and "maximum dynamic pressure" sounds, at least to the lay/uninformed person that it's a point where something is likely to go wrong. Thus, they build a little suspense and keep eyeballs glued to the screen. Perhaps a bit silly/pointless when you think about it, especially if, as has been said, structure is one of the most reliable parts and Max-Q would have been well accounted for in design of the vehicle and its launch profile.

Comment: @AnthonyX Several space agencies, as well as launch companies do their own webcasts using technical people and engineers, and they do it too, so I don't think we can say it's because of "reporters" or "sensationalization". I'm guessing the significance is the necessity to throttle back (losing precious delta-v to gravity) and other complications that happen that gives Max-Q significance to people well versed in launch. Thus I've asked [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22183/12102) to try to flush out why Max-Q is actually "a thing" to take notice of, even for launch experts.

Comment: @JanDoggen yes it does. Q: is max-Q a common failure point? A: no, see this list of failures which mostly lists causes other than dynamic pressure.

Answer (score 7):

The uncrewed [Mercury-Atlas 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury-Atlas_1) flight suffered a catastrophic failure due to aerodynamic loads at or near max-Q, and the launcher's structure was beefed up for future flights:

> [NASA's Owen Maynard] stated in an oral history interview that his post-flight calculations showed the skin of the launch vehicle just below the spacecraft would have buckled due to the combined drag, acceleration, and bending loads which exceeded the resisting tensile stress in the skin provided by internal pressure. Maynard recalled that "The problem of mating the Mercury capsule to the Atlas was far from being properly resolved at the time of MA-1." Based on that finding, the NASA specified that future Mercury-Atlas launch vehicles add doublers to the skin structure in that area, and that future launch trajectories be shallowed to reduce pitch angle rate, to reduce the bending stress on the launch vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much that the max-Q point itself is dangerous, the vehicle acceleration is managed to keep aerodynamic forces to levels that shouldn't be a problem. However, it *is* the most aerodynamically stressful point in the flight, and if the vehicle has some structural fault that would lead to it failing due to those forces, it would likely do so before reaching that point. By the time you've reached it, you've left most of the risk of such failures behind.